# Download Blob in Safari

Tags: download, safari

```
var saveData = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, fileName) {
        var json = JSON.stringify(data),
            blob = new Blob([json], {type: "octet/stream"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());

var data = { x: 42, s: "hello, world", d: new Date() },
    fileName = "my-sample.json";

saveData(data, fileName);
```

The above is working good in chrome and firefox and not in safari as the download attribute of  isn't suppoted by safari , anyother idea to overcome this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick research - I looks like Safari does not support what you are trying to achieve.

The reason why your solution works in Chrome (and Firefox) is that they support the download attribute - Safari doesn't yet.